# Como gerar arquivos excel em lote no MVC?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, mvc

Eu preciso gerar arquivos separados de Excel. Eu tentei fazer num foreach

```
foreach (var item in listExtracts)
        {
            DataTable table = Mytable;
            var grid = new GridView { DataSource = table };

            grid.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ArquivoExcelPessoas.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei outro métodos, em todos no primeiro ele gera o arquivo, mas no loop ele da o erro.

Será que estou fazendo algo errado ou tem outro jeito de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, cada requisição/*request* pode retornar apenas uma resposta/*respose*. Então, a única maneira de retornar isso que vc precisa, seria criando todos os arquivos de Excel em memoria, com um `MemoryStream`, e depois compactar todos em um arquivos **zip**. Então, vc retorna esse arquivo **zip** com todas planilhas Excel que necessitar.

Isso vai, inclusive, reduzir o trafego, já que documento OpenXml possuem alto índice de compactação.